# Inheriting superclass interface

Tags: java, oop

This is the situation:

```
public class Super implements Interface1 {}
public class Sub extends Super {}
```

How could I achieve this?

```
Interface1 listener = (Interface1) subClassObject;
```

being subClassObject a instance of Sub class passed as a param. This is throwing a ClassCastException.
Thanks

Comment: Works for me. You have another problem in your code, or the `Interface1` you think you're casting to isn't the correct one (due to package issues), try doing it with the full package and not only class name

Comment: Works for me too. You can also do simple dynamic binding as provided by Marv.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using this listener object doing a wrong downcasting elsewhere? Just a thought.....

Comment: voted to close. As written there are no problems. Please update your question with detailed information about the `ClassCastException`'s error message/stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

This works without casting:

```
interface MyInterface {}
class Super implements MyInterface {}
class Sub extends Super {}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyInterface i = new Sub();
    }
}
```

Throws no exceptions.

### edit

> Imagine that the object was passed as a param

This also works flawlessly:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         myMethod(new Sub());
    }

    public static void myMethod(Sub s) {
        MyInterface i = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment than an answer.

Comment: Imagine that the object was passed as a param

Comment: `Interface1 listener = (Interface1) subClassObject;` ← this works just fine on my end. You should post the stack trace and perhaps more of your code.